# how to dynamically change color using the defined attribute

Tags: android, colors, attributes, textview, android-theme

Having two theme, it can be dynamically switched.

There is a txtColor attribute defined in
attrs.xml

```
<attr name=“txtColor” format="reference" />
```

in themes.xml, defined the color for the attribute in different theme

```
<style name=“CustomLight" parent="AppTheme.Base">
    <item name="txtColor”>#000000</item>

<style name=“CustomDark" parent="AppTheme.Base">
    <item name="txtColor”>#ffffff</item>
```

in layout file, using the attribute is fine

```
android:textColor="?attr/txtColor"
```

but got exception when try to use the txtColor attribute

```
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f010015
txtView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.attr.txtColor));
```

question: how to change the color dynamically using the attribute?

Comment: can you show how you call the `txtView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.attr.txtColor));`

Comment: @Akis, not sure what you ask for, it is a TextView and txtView.setTextColor() to set the color (supposed to be with the color resource id).

Answer (score 2):

First the attribute format should be "color"

`<attr name="txtColor" format="color"/>`

Then you can set the color doing this:

```
int[] attrs = {R.attr.txtColor} ;
try { //getPackageManager() can throw an exeption
    Activity activity = getActivity();
    themeId = activity.getPackageManager().getActivityInfo(activity.getComponentName(), 0).theme;
    TypedArray ta = activity.obtainStyledAttributes(themeId, attrs);
    int color = ta.getColor(0, Color.BLACK); //I set Black as the default color
    txtView.setTextColor(color);
    ta.recycle();
} catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I found a simpler solution which worked with the existing attrs, here it in case someone is looking for the same, any simpler ones? Thanks!

```
public static int getColorByThemeAttr(Context context, int attr, int defaultColor) {
    TypedValue typedValue = new TypedValue();
    Resources.Theme theme = context.getTheme();
    boolean got = theme.resolveAttribute(attr, typedValue, true);
    return got ? typedValue.data : defaultColor;
}
```

Comment: can we use returned value directly in setBackgroundColorRes/setBackgroundColorInt or do we have to check if it is a valid color value?

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Iannyf and @Juan Cruz Soler answers, I want to provide a complete answer.
First of all generate an `xml` file called `attrs.xml` under `values` section and write your attributes as a color like this:

```
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="FullscreenAttrs">
        <attr name="colorPrimary" format="color" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

Then you can use this line of code to apply color to your `ImageView` as an Icon based on @Iaanyf function:

```
imageView.setColorFilter(getColorByThemeAttr(context,R.attr.colorPrimary,R.color.your_color));
```